# Get random array element where value not equal

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array:

```
arr = ["blue", "red", "green"];
```

How can I get a random element from the array except the element with value `"red"`?

I know I an use the following to get a random array element but how do I put a "where/if" statement?

Comment: Create another array without `red` element. Now the problem is well defined and easy to google for.

Answer (score 7):

The code that is *guaranteed* to complete would look like this:

```
var arr = ["blue", "red", "green"];

var onlyValidValues = arr.filter(v => v !== 'red');

if (onlyValidValues.length === 0) {
    throw new Error('empty array');
}

var randomItem = onlyValidValues[Math.floor(Math.random() * onlyValidValues.length)];
```

So compared to other suggestions it only picks random values from an array cleaned from the "forbidden" elements.

Answer (score 2):

Use **[`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)** within a while loop

```js
var arr = ["blue", "red", "green"],
  val = 'red';

while (val == 'red')
  val = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]

console.log(val);
```

---

Or copy the array and remove red from it, then get an element

```js
var arr = ["blue", "red", "green"],
  arrNew = arr.slice(0); // copy the array
arrNew.splice(arr.indexOf('red'), 1); // remove red from it

val = arrNew[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrNew.length)] //get random element

console.log(val);
```

---

In case there is multiple `red` elements in array, then use `filter()` as in ***@zerkms*** answer.

Comment: This may never complete.

Comment: @zerkms I think cosmic rays causing the code to error is more likely

Comment: @2426021684 the standard does not put any constraints on the implementation of `Math.random`. So having `Math.random = function() { return 0.42; }` would still keep the engine implementation standard complaint.

Comment: @zerkms What kind of implementation hard codes Math.random?

Comment: @2426021684 It's a different question, I'm just saying what the standard requires and what it does not.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
arr = ["blue", "red", "green"];

getRandomChoice = function(arr) {
    var choice = arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)];
    while (choice === "red") {
        choice = arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)];
    }
    return choice;
}

getRandomChoice(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be useful..

```
var arr = ["blue", "red", "green"];
var item = arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)];
while(item == "red"){
item = arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)];

}
document.write(item)
```

Hope it helps to solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

I've done a function using new ES6 features.
With my function you can exclude more than one element.
Here's my approach :

```js
const arr = ["blue", "red", "green"];

function getRandomElementExcluding (...excluded){
  try {
    let random = Math.ceil(Math.random() * arr.length - 1);
    
    if(excluded === undefined)
      return arr[random];
    else if (excluded.includes(arr[random])) 
      return getRandomElementExcluding(...excluded);
    else 
      return arr[random];
  } catch (e){
    return false;
  }
}

console.log( getRandomElementExcluding('red') );
// console.log( getRandomElementExcluding('red', 'green', 'blue') ); It will return false;
```

Comment: @zerkms Math.floor(Math.random() * onlyValidValues.length) used in your answer will improve my function ?

Comment: it's okay. It happens!! haha =)